# Is there any occasion in which an Endpoint is not a RouteEndpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I m trying to understand what is the difference between Asp.net core objects: **Endpoint** and **RouteEndpoint**.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any occasion in which an Endpoint is not a RouteEndpoint

Maybe!

> I'm trying to understand what is the difference between Asp.net core objects: Endpoint and RouteEndpoint.

- `Endpoint` is an abstract class in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` assembly.
- `RouteEndpoint` is an implementation of that `Endpoint` class, and it's in ASP.NET Core's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll` assembly.

The `Endpoint` class is part of ASP.NET Core's hosting infrastructure (because your host executable (i.e. your web-server program, like Kestrel needs it), while `RouteEndpoint` is for your application-code to use.

The functionality is split into these two different types for various reasons - but I imagine some of the main reasons are that:

- The host web-server is *not* concerned about routing (which is an application-level concern), it only needs to tell the application "here, process this request" which it does with `RequestDelegate`.

  - You might notice that many (most?) of Microsoft's developer projects ship
    with at least two NuGet packages or .NET assemblies: `Microsoft.Something.Abstractions.dll` and `Microsoft.Something.dll`. The `Abstractions.dll` assembly is used by code which needs to interact indirectly with `Microsoft.Something.dll` but without taking a hard dependency on a fast-moving assembly which may break things or be a pain to keep updating.
- It enables the routing system in ASP.NET Core to be updated separately from the lower-level web-server part, as that's more likely to have bugs in it or have its requirements change.
- It also enables applications to implement their own routing engine without breaking compatibility with the ASP.NET Core host webserver's interfaces.
- And [loose-coupling is a key part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) of any well-engineered software system design.

So...

- If you're developing applications on top of ASP.NET Core and you're not getting deep into its routing system, then you only need to use `RouteEndpoint`.
- If you're building your own ASP.NET Core host system, then only use the `Endpoint` abstract class so that your program can host other applications using different versions of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll` assembly or their own routing system.

Comment: Dai: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. It has surely made the subject clear to me. :)